# JavaScript regex for alphanumeric string with length of 3-5 chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regex for validating alphanumeric String with length of 3-5 chars. I tried following regex found from the web, but it didn't even catch alphanumerics correctly.

```
var myRegxp = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$/;
if(myRegxp.test(value) == false)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Consider learning to read regexes so you can figure out which satisfy your needs and which don't. Or better yet, so you can write your own.

Comment: That is good idea, but i don't have time for this task to do that, but of course that's what i'll have to do.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

add `{3,5}` to your expression which means length between 3 to 5

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){3,5}$/
```

Comment: do you need the parenthesis?

Comment: @EralpB yes we need parenthesis('()') to check the length of alphanumeric as a whole

Comment: Its not working in JS...am I missing something here ('s' is the string to be matched)?
```const pattern = '/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){3,40}$/'; const res = s.match(pattern)
```

Answer (score 6):

You'd have to define alphanumerics exactly, but

```
/^(\w{3,5})$/
```

Should match any digit/character/_ combination of length 3-5.

If you also need the dash, <strike>make sure to escape it (`\-`)</strike> add it, like this: :

```
/^([\w\-]{3,5})$/
```

Also: the `^` *anchor* means that the sequence has to start at the beginning of the line (character string), and the `$` that it ends at the end of the line (character string). So your `value` string mustn't contain anything else, or it won't match.

Comment: You don't need to escape the dash if it's the first or last character inside a character class.

Comment: Didn't know that (and I have been using regex for decades ;-). Thanks. But it doesn't hurt either, right?

Answer (score 4):

First this script test the strings N having chars from 3 to 5.

For **multi** language (**arabic**, **Ukrainian**) you **Must** use this

```
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\u0600-\u065f\u066a-\u06EF\u06fa-\u06ff\ufb8a\u067e\u0686\u06af\u0750-\u077f\ufb50-\ufbc1\ufbd3-\ufd3f\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufe70-\ufefc\uFDF0-\uFDFD]+){3,5}$/;  regex.test('мшефн');
```

Other wise 
the below is for **English** Alphannumeric only

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){3,5}$/
```

P.S  the above dose not accept special characters

one final thing the above dose not take space as test it will fail if there is space if you want space then add  after the 0-9\s

```
\s
```

And if you want to check lenght of all string add **dot .**

```
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s@,!=%$#&_-\u0600-\u065f\u066a-\u06EF\u06fa-\u06ff\ufb8a\u067e\u0686\u06af\u0750-\u077f\ufb50-\ufbc1\ufbd3-\ufd3f\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufe70-\ufefc\uFDF0-\uFDFD]).{1,30}$/;
```