# javascript Regex to have atmost 5 characters in password

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I am trying to implement maximum case in JavaScript for password validation.

I have a scenario where in password user should enter maximum 5 characters (a-z,A-Z) and password length having no restriction

1. Passsword length no limit
2. except (a-z,A-Z) ,there is no limtation
3. charcter(a-z,A-Z) will have atmost 5 in password .Not more than that.Sequence doesnot matter.

I tried `/[^A-Z,a-z]*(?:[A-Z,a-z][^A-Z,a-z]*){0,5}/`

But it is not working.
Kindly help

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: General advice for this sort of thing: Don't try to do it with a single regex, don't try to do every test with regex.

Comment: He wants the passwort to be as long as the user wants but has less or equal than 5 charaters [a-zA.Z].

Comment: I need a regex to test my "password" to contain max 5 alphabet(a-z,A-Z) in any sequence.user can input other things in any number and sequence

Answer (score 0):

Did you even search? It is obviously, that this is a duplicate.

See

- [Regex javascript for Minimum 8 characters,at least one number and one special character, maximum 32 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543972/regex-javascript-for-minimum-8-characters-at-least-one-number-and-one-special-ch)
- [Password REGEX with min 6 chars, at least one letter and one number and may contain special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844359/password-regex-with-min-6-chars-at-least-one-letter-and-one-number-and-may-cont)
- [JavaScript regex for alphanumeric string with length of 3-5 chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745112/javascript-regex-for-alphanumeric-string-with-length-of-3-5-chars)

Answer (score 0):

You can just count how many characters you have in the password like so:

```
if(password.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g).length > 5){ /* reject */ }
```

Comment: reject on > 5? Type mismatch?

Comment: @iquellis no, that's exactly the requirement. `charcter(a-z,A-Z) will have atmost 5 in password. Not more than that.`

Comment: Oops, yes, you are right. Was thinking of password policy or sth. like that.

Comment: This is a regex flag. `g` is the global flag and allows you to find all matches instad of just one. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below regex for password validation.

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{5,20})
```

It validates :

1. Must contain ! digit [0-9]
2. One lowercase character [a-z]
3. One uppercase character [A-Z]
4. One symbol [@#$%]
5. Length of password must be between [5-20].

Comment: I need a regex to test my "password" to contain max 5 alphabet(a-z,A-Z) in any sequence.user can input other things in any number and sequence .Can i get specific regex instead of in combination

Comment: Can you tell some example how your password would look like?@SudhanshuAgarwal

Answer (score 0):

**Break it down and solve it step by step**

Alphabet only - define your character set

```
/[A-Za-z]/
```

Maximum length of 5 - use a quantifier

```
/[A-Za-z]{0,5}/
```

Nothing else is allowed - wrap it with ^ and $

```
/^[A-Za-z]{0,5}$/
```

Comment: I need a regex to test my "password" to contain max 5 alphabet(a-z, A-Z) in any sequence.user can input other things in any number and sequence.Can i get specific regex for my requirement?This will only test string which are having max 5 characters, no other input.But in my case max 5 character with any number or sequence of other input

Comment: Sorry mate, I didn't understand your question at first. Bellian's solution is the best one but you need to do one more check in case password.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g) returns null when it doesn't find any a-zA-Z character in the password